# Extracting the correct link in multiple DIVs using beautiful soup. It is not a duplicate question

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code below extracts links from multiple DIVs with identical class and prints them correctly. However in each DIV there are several links. I want to extract and print only the first link in each DIV. What Syntax should I use to accomplish this.

```
This is the structure of the DIVs:

<div class="details">
    <h1 class="detail_summary"><a href="/detailed description/">cars</a></h1>
    <h1 class="detail_1"><a href="/detailed description/">planes</a></h1>
    <h1 class="detail_2"><a href="/detailed description/">bikes</a></h1>
</div>   

This is the code:     

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://www.placeholder.com/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
data = bs.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'details'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print (a['href'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find` instead of `findAll`. It will find the first link only.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="details">
    <h1 class="detail_summary"><a href="/detailed description/">cars</a></h1>
    <h1 class="detail_1"><a href="/detailed description/">planes</a></h1>
    <h1 class="detail_2"><a href="/detailed description/">bikes</a></h1>
</div>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = bs.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'details'})
for div in data:
    print(div.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works! Before I asked the question I was aware about the find however in my print statement I neglected to add the div. before the find and therefore it did not work for me. Thank you again for your help.